# C# String Format give wrong result

Tags: c#, format

I'm trying to format a string of 6 digits with the following format:

1234/56.

I'm using the following:

```
string.Format("123456", "{0000/00}");
```

Result 123456

Comment: First off you've got the format string and paramters mixed up.  Second that's not a valid format string.  I suggest you read the [`string.Format` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).  Finally the type of formatting you're attempting doesn't make sense with a `string`.  the "123456" should be a numeric value like an `int`.  Basically you seem to want this `string.Format("{0:0000/00}", 123456)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
string.Format("{0:####/##}",123456)
```

I tested the code and is working.

For reference on string formatting please visit:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: Thank you All for your suggestions

Comment: @Sami it would be really nice if you edit your question so this post can actually answer what is asked. If you did not notice, the question (presumably written by you) asks about "format *a string* of 6 digits" which is completely different from suggestion in this post that talks about integer formatting. I.e. splitting "000001" will produce significantly different result vs. `000001.ToString("####/##")`....

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
var number = int.Parse("123456");
var formattedNumber = number.ToString("####/##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Edit to include zero fill (if required):

```
var number = int.Parse("123456");
var formattedNumber = number.ToString("####/##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(7,'0');
```

You will still have issues with any number below 10 (i.e "000009") showing up as 0000/9. In which you are probably better off with a substring modification like below.

```
var text = "123456";
var formattedNumber = text.Substring(0, 4) + "/" + text.Substring(4, 2);
```

Comment: How this answers "format a string of 6 digits" question? `int number=123456;` is *not* a string...

Comment: edited to more correctly match the form of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numbers I would use @rob-s 's example above.  If you are dealing with actual strings then you can use the following code sample.

```
var value = "123456";
var index = value.Length - 2;
var formattedValue = $"{value.Substring(0, index)}/{value.Substring(index)}";
Console.WriteLine(formattedValue);
```

Your output will look like what you have described in your question.

1234/56